# google map blank screen, programmatic added

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have put the google map service on by console, and generate a debug key.

I've debug it, the mMap and mLocation both are not null. I can get latitude and longitude successfully.

But the map is still blank.

Please help.

sam

here is the layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f2f5fa"
tools:context=".LocFm" >
<!-- top bar component -->
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loc_topbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/topbar" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/loc_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loc_backBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/loc_title"
    android:textColor="#171717"              
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_font" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loc_backBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/backbtn" />
 <!-- BODY -->

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/map_fragment"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/loc_topbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/loc_bottombar"
    >
<!-- Put fragments dynamically -->
</FrameLayout>


 <!-- bottom bar component -->
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/loc_bottombar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
     android:background="@drawable/bottombar" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/locBtn"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/halfbutton_width"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/halfbutton_height"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loc_bottombar"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/halfbutton_marginTop"
     android:background="@drawable/halfbutton_bg"
     android:text="@string/button_Loc" 
     android:textSize="@dimen/button_font"/>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/loc_nextBtn"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/halfbutton_width"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/halfbutton_height"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loc_bottombar"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/halfbutton_marginTop"
     android:background="@drawable/halfbutton_bg"
     android:text="@string/button_Continue" 
     android:textSize="@dimen/button_font"/>

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/nextImg"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loc_nextBtn"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loc_nextBtn"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/buttonicon_marginRight"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttonicon_marginTop"
     android:src="@drawable/next" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/locImg"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/locBtn"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locBtn"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/buttonicon_marginRight"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttonicon_marginTop"
     android:src="@drawable/location" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my api key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map.LocFm"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.map;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class LocFm extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,   ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
Timer positionTimer;
private GoogleMap mMap;     
private Location mLocation;
private UiSettings mUiSettings;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private static SupportMapFragment mMapView;
private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "map";
public FragmentManager fManager;
double latitude, longitude, radius;
String sLat,sLong,sRange;
boolean bMaploaded=false;
int index =0;
int positionCount=0;
final int POSITION_COUNT_MAX=5;
final int POSITION_MIN=100;
final int PSSITION_MAX_TIMES=10;

OnlineHistoryInfo onLineHistory;

ProgressDialog dialog;

 private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
      .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
      .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
      .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setLocFm();     
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected()) 
    {
        mLocation=mLocationClient.getLastLocation();        
    }

    if (mLocation!=null)
    {
        latitude= mLocation.getLatitude();

        longitude= mLocation.getLongitude();    

        radius=mLocation.getAccuracy();

        sLat=Double.toString(latitude);
        sLong=Double.toString(longitude);
        sRange=Double.toString(radius);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(getString(R.string.map_msg)));

    }

    positionCount++;
    if(mLocationClient==null || radius<=POSITION_MIN)
    {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        positionCount=0;
            Button loc_nextBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loc_nextBtn);
        loc_nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        loc_nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ImageView nextImg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nextImg);
        nextImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showDialog(false,null);
    }

    if(positionCount>=POSITION_COUNT_MAX)
    {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        positionCount=0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
        position();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void mapDestroy()
{
    if (mLocationClient != null)
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    if(mMapView!=null){ 
            FragmentTransaction ft = mMapView.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(mMapView);
            ft.commit();
    }
    if(mMap!=null)
    {
        mMap=null;
    }
    bMaploaded=false;
}
 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {


  // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
  if (mMap == null) {
    // Try to obtain the map from the MapFragment.
    mMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (mMap != null) {
      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
  }
 }

  private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
   if (mLocationClient == null) {
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(
      this,
      this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
      this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
  }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.loc_backBtn:
        mapDestroy();
        LocFm.this.finish();    
        break;
    case R.id.loc_nextBtn:
        positionCount=0;
        mapDestroy();
        break;
    case R.id.locBtn:
        relocate();
        break;
    }

}

public void setLocFm(){
        setContentView(R.layout.loc_fm);

        loadMapFragment();

    ImageView loc_backBtn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loc_backBtn);
    loc_backBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button loc_nextBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loc_nextBtn);
    loc_nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ImageView nextImg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nextImg);
    nextImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Button locBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.locBtn);
    locBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    bMaploaded=true;
}

private void loadMapFragment() {
    showDialog(true,getString(R.string.alert_postion));
    // It isn't possible to set a fragment's id programmatically so we set a tag instead and
    // search for it using that.

   mMapView = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // We only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
   if (mMapView == null) {
        // To programmatically add the map, we first create a SupportMapFragment.
        mMapView = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

        // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_fragment, mMapView, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnected()) mLocationClient.connect();
}


private void position()
{   
    showDialog(true,getString(R.string.alert_postion));
    if (mMap != null) {    
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);  
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);  
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);  
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);   
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);  
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
        mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
        mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
         mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(REQUEST,this);  // LocationListener
    }       
}

public void relocate()
{
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnected()) mLocationClient.connect();
    WSWLog.i("relocate()");
}

/**
 * @param dialgShow
 */
public void showDialog(boolean dialgShow,final String message)
{
    WSWLog.i(" showDialog ("+dialgShow+","+message+")");

    if(dialgShow)
    {
        if(dialog==null)
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);//false

            {
                dialog.setMessage(message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dialog.setMessage(message);
        }
        dialog.show();

        //
        if(null != positionTimer)
        {
            positionTimer.cancel();

        }
        positionTimer= new Timer(true);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){  
               public void run() { 
                   handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);    
            }  
         };

        positionTimer.schedule(task,PSSITION_MAX_TIMES*1000, PSSITION_MAX_TIMES*1000); 
    }
    else
    {
        if(null != positionTimer)
        {
            positionTimer.cancel();             
        }

        if(dialog!=null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

 private Handler handler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(null != positionTimer)
            {
                positionTimer.cancel();
            }
            showDialog(false,null);
            //
            alertNoPosition();

            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

/**
 */
private void alertNoPosition()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.loc_alert_realloc));          builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.button_Loc)); 

    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.button_Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();   
            LocFm.this.finish();
        }
    });


    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.button_OK), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            relocate();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

}

Comment: what does LogCat tell ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor LogCat has no errors. Everything seems fine.But just no maps. I can locate my location by travelling around with no problem. If I debug the project, map and location is not null!

Comment: Are you sure you have created Map Api key with the combination of your package name and the Keystore

Comment: finding location has nothing to do with map. you can even find location without map also. please check if you are getting map .

Comment: @GauravSharma please see my last post. with android:required="false", the map can be shown, but mLocationClient.connect() will not work. As the OnConnected() events can't be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

First check your debug key whether you are using right one? second use following permission. Remove repeated permission from manifest.xml.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
    android:required="false" />
```

Use supportmap fragment instead of simple fragment

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
```

follow this simple tutorial you may find it usefull http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/12/google-rolls-out-android-maps-api-v2/

your code is not clear...

try this when you are showing lat-long on your map. i could not find this in your code

```
mCurrentLattitude = mGPSListener.GetLatitudeRaw();
    mCurrentLongitude = mGPSListener.GetLongitudeRaw();
    LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(mCurrentLattitude, mCurrentLongitude);
    Log.d("MAP"," setCurrentLocation lat-lang values: "+mCurrentLattitude +" : "+mCurrentLongitude);
    CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinates);
    String lPreviousZoomLevelString = Config.getSetting(getApplicationContext(), "MAPZOOMLEVEL");
    mPreviousZoomLevel = Float.parseFloat(lPreviousZoomLevelString);
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(mPreviousZoomLevel);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    CameraPosition  i = mMap.getCameraPosition();       
    Log.d("MAP"," after setting zoom 2 :"+i.zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
```

Comment: The debug key surely the correct one. If I added the required="false", map can be shown, but I can't locate my location. the mLocationClient.connect() will not work.

If you read my code carefully, you will find I dynamically added this SupportMapFragment by:

    mMapView=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);</br>
    if (mMapView==null) {
        mMapView=SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
       ...

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what's happened. However, here is the step I took:

1. I took the advice by Gaurav Sharma, make the permission required="false"
2. This caused the onConnected() can't be triggered.
3. Then I changed the permission required="true". The map magically displayed! what a amazing google map!

Anyway, the map is shown. Don't know what's wrong. Thanks @GauravSharma