# with googlemap release key, blank map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have enough with google map api.
The map works well with debug key. After I generate a new api key with signed keystore, with this new release api key, the map is gone.

Here is my step:

1. with my signed keystone, use keytool to show SHA1 code.
2. with this SHA1 code and the package name, I go to Google APIs Console to generate a new api key.
3. I used this new api key in manifest.
4. Build the project.
5. Export signed application package.
6. the map is blank, but it is still can be located.

What's wrong with it?

sam

Comment: Post your code, google map API v2 is lazy sometimes ;)

Comment: @Yume117 Are you sure the you need the code because the code is very long. As my problem is with debug api key, it's worked, but not with release key.

Comment: In that case you need to check you package name, your permissions, and if nothing is working you can try to regenerate a signed APikey for map. You can still post the map part of your manifest, the map part layout, ..etc juste the part using google map

Comment: @Yume117 please see my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807530/google-map-blank-screen-programmatic-added

Comment: @Yume117 I mean the code is on my previous question. thx, sam.

Comment: Seen it, why do you want to put the map fragment dynamically ?